# How to solve recurrence relation with multiple parameters?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

> Divide a square using horizontal and vertical lines into 16 equal
> smaller squares as follow: [image]
>
> A counter is placed at random on one of these squares and is then
> moved $n$ times. At each of these moves it can be transferred to any
> neighbouring square, in any of the 8 directions with equal
> probability.
>
> let $c_n$ be the probability that a particular corner site is occupied
> after $n$ such independent moves, and let the corresponding
> probabilities for an intermediate site at the side of the board and
> for a site in the middle of the board be $s_n$ and $m_n$ respectively.
> Show that
>
> $4c_n+8s_n+4m_n=1$, $n=0,1,2,...,$. and that
> $c_n=\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$, $n=1,2,...$. Find two
> other relations for $s_n$ and $m_n$ in terms of $c_{n-1}, s_{n-1}$,
> and $m_{n-1}$ and hence find $c_n, s_n$ and $m_n$. (Oxford 1974M).

I think $c_n=\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$ should be $c_n=\frac{1}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$

And $s_n=s_{n-1}\frac{2}{5}+c_{n-1}\frac{2}{3}+m_{n-1}\frac{1}{2}$

And $m_n=m_{n-1}\frac{3}{8}+s_{n-1}\frac{2}{5}+c_{n-1}\frac{1}{3}$.

Also, $c_0=\frac{1}{4}, s_0=\frac{1}{2}, m_n=\frac{1}{4}$.

How do we solve for $c_n,s_n,m_n$?

Comment: "Oxford 1974M" means what?

Comment: I don't know. It was written like that in the question.

Comment: Can the counter still move in 8 directions when they are on the edge or at the corners? BTW is this not a Markov chain problem?

Comment: @user 42493: A reference to the book would be welcome.

Comment: yea it is :Probability by Geoffrey Grimmett and Dominic Welsh

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin, the counter the corner has 3 directions to move only. So how do you solve this using Markov chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c_n,s_n,m_n$ are the respective probabilities, starting from a random cell, of ending, after $n$ moves, in a *particular* corner cell, side cell, or middle cell.

Let $C_n,S_n,M_n$ be the the respective probabilities, starting from a random cell, of ending, after $n$ moves, in *some* corner cell, side cell, or middle cell (where we don't care which one).

It's automatic that
$$C_n+S_n+M_n=1$$
and clearly we have
$$
\begin{cases}
C_n=4c_n\\[4pt]
S_n=8s_n\\[4pt]
M_n=4m_n\\
\end{cases}
$$
hence
$$4c_n+8s_n+4m_n=1$$
which resolves the first part of the problem.

Note that in your attempt, the recursions you came up with are really for $C_n,S_n,M_n$, rather than for $c_n,s_n,m_n$.

Thus, for $C_n,S_n,M_n$ we get the initial conditions
$$C_0=\frac{1}{4},\;\;\;S_0=\frac{1}{2},\;\;\;M_0=\frac{1}{4}$$
together with the recurrence relations
$$
\begin{cases}
C_n
=
{\large{\frac{1}{5}}}S_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{8}}}M_{n-1}
\\[4pt]
S_n
=
{\large{\frac{2}{5}}}S_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{2}{3}}}C_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}M_{n-1}\\[4pt]
M_n
=
{\large{\frac{3}{8}}}M_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{2}{5}}}S_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{3}}}C_{n-1}
\\
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\ge 1$.

For $c_n,s_n,m_n$, the corresponding results are
$$c_0=\frac{1}{16},\;\;\;s_0=\frac{1}{16},\;\;\;m_0=\frac{1}{16}$$
together with the recurrence relations
$$
\begin{cases}
c_n
=
{\large{\frac{2}{5}}}s_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{8}}}m_{n-1}
\\[4pt]
s_n
=
{\large{\frac{2}{5}}}s_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{3}}}c_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{4}}}m_{n-1}\\[4pt]
m_n
=
{\large{\frac{3}{8}}}m_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{4}{5}}}s_{n-1}
+
{\large{\frac{1}{3}}}c_{n-1}
\\
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\ge 1$.

For each nonnegative integer $k$, let $v_k$ denote the vector $\langle{c_k,s_k,m_k}\rangle$.

Then in matrix form, for $n\ge 1$, we have $v_n=Tv_{n-1}$
where
$$
T=
{\large{
\pmatrix
{
0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{8} \cr
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{4} \cr
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{8} \cr
}
}}
$$
It follows that for all positive integers $n$, we have $v_n=T^nv_0$.

Noting that $T$ has minimal polynomial
$$t^3-{\small{\frac{31}{40}}}t^2-{\small{\frac{9}{40}}}t$$
we get
$$T^3={\small{\frac{31}{40}}}T^2+{\small{\frac{9}{40}}}T$$
hence, for all integers $n\ge 3$,
\begin{align*}
&T^n={\small{\frac{31}{40}}}T^{n-1}+{\small{\frac{9}{40}}}T^{n-2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&T^nv_0={\small{\frac{31}{40}}}T^{n-1}v_0+{\small{\frac{9}{40}}}T^{n-2}v_0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&v_n={\small{\frac{31}{40}}}v_{n-1}+{\small{\frac{9}{40}}}v_{n-2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which yields the recurrence relations
\begin{align*}
c_n&=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{16}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=0\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{21}{640}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=1\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{931}{25600}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=2\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{31}{40}}}c_{n-1}+{\large{\frac{9}{40}}}c_{n-2}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n\ge 3\\
\end{cases}
\\[14pt]
s_n&=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{16}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=0\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{59}{960}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=1\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{2269}{38400}}}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n=2\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{31}{40}}}s_{n-1}+{\large{\frac{9}{40}}}s_{n-2}&&\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;n\ge 3\\
\end{cases}
\\[14pt]
m_n&=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{16}}}&&\text{if}\;\;n=0\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{181}{1920}}}&&\text{if}\;\;n=1\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{7331}{76800}}}&&\text{if}\;\;n=2\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{31}{40}}}m_{n-1}+{\large{\frac{9}{40}}}m_{n-2}&&\text{if}\;\;n\ge 3\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Finally, using standard linear-recurrence-solving techniques, together with the initial values
$$c_0=\frac{1}{16},\;\;\;s_0=\frac{1}{16},\;\;\;m_0=\frac{1}{16}$$
we get the formulas
\begin{align*}
c_n&=\frac{1}{28}+\frac{13}{1008}\cdot\left(-\frac{9}{40}\right)^n\\[4pt]
s_n&=\frac{5}{84}-\frac{13}{1512}\cdot\left(-\frac{9}{40}\right)^n\\[4pt]
m_n&=\frac{2}{21}+\frac{13}{3024}\cdot\left(-\frac{9}{40}\right)^n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
valid for all positive integers $n$.